# How long did it take arriving passengers to become indentured servants and where did they stay until then?

Tags: economy, colonial-america, american-revolution, immigration, labour-history

In colonial times just prior to the Revolution, when passengers arrived to the New World on a ship, how long would it typically take for them to be indentured to someone? For example, would they typically be indentured on the day of arrival, or was it common for it to take several days or weeks? If it wasn't immediate, then what were living conditions like in the interim, and how were they prevented from escaping?

Comment: Weren't they indentured prior to boarding the ship? The cost of the voyage was usually a part of the debt they had to pay off.

Comment: I think in some cases, but not always, or maybe the indenture was sold to someone else when they landed. They were typically indentured to land owners, who weren't the same companies operating the ships.

Comment: @A.DuffL Show your research for all claims made in the question (and in explanatory comments not yet incorporated into the question).

Comment: In particular, where do you get the claim that indentured persons had to be "prevented from escaping"? The U.S. still has indentured labour today, namely minor league sports contracts. I don't see a great line up of minor league baseball players lining up "trying to escape" their contracts. Further: just where would one escape to, in a continent of small villages, with no public transport, surrounded by (mostly, at least somewhat) hostile natives.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786). Question is based on assumptions presented without evidence. Is this question answered by [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentured_servitude)?  "  they signed an indenture in return for a costly passage." Recommend the question be closed, edited to address the definition of/history of [indenture](https://guides.loc.gov/indentured-servants)/ and the re-opened

Comment: While there is now an answer, and I prefer answered questions to be opened. I believe that revision of this question to present preliminary research would benefit the site.  If new users spot the pattern that _all_ questions have preliminary research, it helps to communicate our community expectations.

Comment: "Rind's Virginia Gazette" dated June 15, 1775 page 3, showing rewards for escaped indentured servants alongside similar rewards for escaped slaves and strayed animals. It's not a point of contention that indentured servants tried to escape, it's pretty well established and accepted in historical circles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indentured servitude took several forms in the colonial period. A web site [here](https://gunstonhall.org/learn/people-of-gunston-hall/indentured-servants/#:%7E:text=Indentured%20servants%20were%20men%20and,%2C%20King%27s%20passengers%2C%20and%20redemptioners.) discusses this.

> Indentured servants were men and women who willingly signed a contract
> in which they agreed to work for a certain number of years to
> compensate for their voyage to America.
>
> Three different types of indentured servant agreements existed in the
> 18th century: free-willers, King’s passengers, and redemptioners.

The third category, the redemptioners, seems to best fit the focus of the question, and indeed mentions a timeline to repay the voyage costs before having their contract sold on the open market:

> Free-will indentured servants decided to come to America on their own
> merit and willingly signed a contract before departing England. King’s
> passengers, also known as convict servants, were criminals who were
> sent to America to serve a term of seven or fourteen years, depending
> on the crime they committed. Finally, ***redemptioners were passengers
> who were given two weeks to redeem the price of their voyage once they
> got to America and if they were unable to make the payment, they were
> sold to the highest bidder.***